# Pokemon go, not getting the option of which google account to login on

Tags: pokemon-go

Hi trying to transfer my lads account from my wife's iPhone to his android phone. when a do it, it just installs my pokemon account and does give the option to choose his? I've signed out of all accounts but still does not give an option when logging in. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you can only select from Google accounts that have been added to the phone itself. You'll need to add his Google account in order to get a pop-up window to select between multiple accounts. 
That means you'll need to take steps to not sync all his email, contacts, calendars, etc. as well if you just want to have his account available for games, but it's doable:
In near-stock Android, you'll go into Settings, then Accounts, and FIRST turn OFF auto-sync for all accounts. 
THEN add his Google account (gmail address and password). 
THEN turn on airplane mode so it won't actually be able to sync, and turn auto-sync back on. 
Tap on his account name to see individual sync settings and UNCHECK everything except "App data". 
NOW back out and turn off airplane mode, and you've got the ability to log in as him without clogging up your phone with all his email and such as well.